# RADIUS authentication on Cisco switches: how to assign privilege levels?

Tags: cisco, authentication, radius, ios, windows-ias-server

I need to configure some Cisco switches (IOS 12.x) to authenticate against a RADIUS server; the server is Windows Server 2003's IAS, and it validates users against his Active Directory domain.

I know how to configure the switches to validate usernames/passwords against the RADIUS server, and I can succesfully login using an AD account; the question is: how can I set privilege level 15 for users, in order to not have to use `enable` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [How to Assign Privilege Levels with TACACS+ and RADIUS](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk59/technologies_tech_note09186a008009465c.shtml)

Comment: I found that soon after posting the question :-) But I'm still accepting your answer, as that page actually helped me a lot. The only difficult bit was setting "shell:priv-lvl=15" on IAS, but it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

send back the cisco-av-pair attribute with a value of "shell:priv-lvl=15".